# How to use typeof in conditional expression

Tags: typescript

I am converting a large project from javascript / jQuery to Typescript / Vue (I'm fairly new to both). It's pretty much all working but I have some left-over typescript errors which I'd like to understand and rectify.
One of them is this:

```
async function readSuccess(event: ProgressEvent<FileReader>) {
  let routeXML = '';
  if (event.target === null) {
    alert('Cannot read file');
    return;
  }
  if ((typeof event.target.result) !== "string") {
    alert('File contents have incorrect type');
    return;
  }
  routeXML = event.target.result;
  ....
  ....
}
```

which is giving the error (on the assignment of `routeXML`)

```
Type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2322)
```

but the lines above should mean that `event.target.result` cannot be `null`. So how do I correct this? The code runs correctly, it's just that the TS compiler isn't happy.

Comment: I think the brackets around your `typeof` statement are stopping TS from correctly narrowing the type.

Comment: Yeah, this is [ms/TS#42203](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42203).  @DBS, do you want to write up an answer saying that or should I?

Comment: @jcalz Go for it, I know enough to pick it up as a problem, but not enough to clearly explain the cause.